# Find and get the location of a list of words in a text

Tags: regex, perl, match

I'm sure this is simple but I just can't figure out what to do...
I have a text file with a bunch of words in it (let's call it "wordlist") organized in a single column. Then I have a big text file (let's call it "essay"). What I want to do is to look in the "essay" file for the words in my "wordlist".
The trick is that I want to know the position of the matched word in the "essay" (meaning, match found after X characters).

I'm actually able to do it when I look for a single word (so wordlist containing just 1 word) but I can't get it to work when working with a **list** of words...
Any advice ?

thanks a lot

Ok so I just realized it would just tell me "no match found" anyway...Here is the code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open (my $wordlist, "<", "/wordlist.txt")
    or die "cannot open < wordlist.txt $!";

open (my $essay, "<", "/essay.txt")
    or die "cannot open < essay.txt $!";


while (<$essay>)    { print "match found\n" if ($essay =~ m/$wordlist/) ; }
            { print "no match found\n" if ($essay !~ m/$wordlist/) ; }
```

Help please...?

Comment: Please show your code so we can find the problem

Comment: If you know how to do it for one word, you can repeat the procedure for multiple words.

Comment: Is the `essay.txt` also a single column file or just a free text file?

Answer (score 1):

perl index function basically matches substring which does not ensure the match of a full string. A regular expression based match is more useful here imho.

**Explanation:**

- Read whole text of essay in a string. => `$essay`
- For each word from wordlist.txt => `$_`
- -- Keep matching `$_` within `$essay` with proper regex. The one used here is `b$_\b`
- -- For each match, collect the value of `@-[0]`

`\b`: is the word boundary character here which ensures that it only matches with complete words not substrings.

`@-`: is a special variable that contains the start position of the last regex match.

Here is a sample code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $wordlist_file = 'wordlist.txt';
open my $wordlist_fh, '<', $wordlist_file or die "Failed to open '$wordlist_file': $!";

my %pos;

my $essay_file = 'essay.txt';
my $essay = do {
    local $/ = undef;
    open my $fh, "<", $essay_file
        or die "could not open $essay_file: $!";
    <$fh>;
};

while (<$wordlist_fh>) {
    chomp;
    $pos{$_} = [] unless $pos{$_};
    while($essay =~ m/\b$_\b/g){
      push @{$pos{$_}}, @-;
    }
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(\%pos);
```

the wordlist file and essay files are similar as mentioned by ThisSuitIsBlackNot.

**wordlist.txt**

```
I
Perl
hacker
```

**essay.txt**

```
I want to be just another Perl hacker when I grow up
I want to be just another Perl hacker when I grow up
```

The %pos hash now contains all the positions of your each word. I just showed them through dumper

```
$VAR1 = {
          'hacker' => [
                        '31',
                        '84'
                      ],
          'Perl' => [
                      '26',
                      '79'
                    ],
          'I' => [
                   '0',
                   '43',
                   '53',
                   '96'
                 ]
        };
```

Note that the counts are including the newline characters at the end of each line.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use index() function.

Here is the link: [Using the Perl index() function](http://perlmeme.org/howtos/perlfunc/index_function.html)

This is my sample. The performance may be not too well. Hope it helps~:)

```
open (my $wordlist, "<", "files/wordlist.txt")
    or die "cannot open < wordlist.txt $!";

open (my $essay, "<", "files/essay.txt")
    or die "cannot open < essay.txt $!";

my $words = {};

while (<$wordlist>) {
    chomp($_);
    $words->{$_} = 1;
}

my $row_count = 0;
while (<$essay>) {
    $row_count++;
    chomp($_);
    foreach my $word (keys %{$words}) {
        my $offset = 0;
        my $r = index($_, $word, $offset);

        while ($r != -1) {
            print "Found [$word] in line $row_count at $r\n";
            $offset = $r + 1;
            $r = index($_, $word, $offset);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `$essay` and `$wordlist` are both filehandles. When you say

```
print "match found\n" if ($essay =~ m/$wordlist/);
```

You're trying to match the *stringification* of one filehandle to the *stringification* of another filehandle. When a filehandle is stringified, it looks something like this:

```
GLOB(0x9a26c38)
```

So your code actually does something like:

```
print "match found\n" if ('GLOB(0x9a26c38)' =~ m/GLOB(0x94bbc38)/);
```

This is not what you want. You need to read the contents of your files and compare those, not the filehandles themselves.

### Essay words each on their own line

The following code assumes that your "essay" consists of one word per line. We read the contents of the essay file into a hash of arrays, with the lines as keys and an array of positions as values. We use an array in case the same word appears multiple times in the file. The position of the first word is zero. We then loop through the word list file, printing the word and the *first* matching position, if there is one.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $essay_file = 'files/essay.txt';
open my $essay_fh, '<', $essay_file or die "Failed to open '$essay_file': $!";

my $pos = 0;
my %essay;

while (<$essay_fh>) {
    chomp;
    push @{ $essay{$_} }, $pos;
    $pos += length $_;
}

my $wordlist_file = 'files/wordlist.txt';
open my $wordlist_fh, '<', $wordlist_file or die "Failed to open '$wordlist_file': $!";

while (<$wordlist_fh>) {
    chomp;
    say "$_: $essay{$_}[0]" if exists $essay{$_};
}
```

*essay.txt*

```
I
want
to
be
just
another
Perl
hacker
when
I
grow
up
```

*wordlist.txt*

```
I
Perl
hacker
```

*Output*

```
I: 0
Perl: 20
hacker: 24
```

Note that I'm ignoring newline characters when computing the position values. You can adjust this as necessary.

### Essay words more than one per line

If your essay file can have more than one word per line, we can use a regex to check for matches:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

# Slurp entire essay file into a variable
my $essay = do {
    local $/;
    my $essay_file = 'files/essay.txt';
    open my $essay_fh, '<', $essay_file or die "Failed to open '$essay_file': $!";
    <$essay_fh>;
};

my $wordlist_file = 'files/wordlist.txt';
open my $wordlist_fh, '<', $wordlist_file or die "Failed to open '$wordlist_file': $!";

while (<$wordlist_fh>) {
    chomp;
    say "$_: ", pos($essay) - length($_) if $essay =~ /\b$_\b/g;
}
```

*essay.txt*

```
I want to be just another Perl hacker when I grow up
```

*wordlist.txt*

```
I
Perl
hacker
hack
```

*Output*

```
I: 0
Perl: 26
hacker: 31
```

Note that the results are a little bit different from our other program, because now there are spaces between words. Also note that there is no output for the word `hack`, since we're only checking for whole word matches.

Comment: `index` will include the occrences of all substrings which may not be a full word. For example, word list contains `super` and there is a word in essay.txt like `supershop` which should not be counted I guess.

Comment: Nice. The main points here are about using `b$_\b` and `pos()` / `@-`. Our answers would be almost same if you just change your `if` to a `while` which would find out multiple occurences of a single word. :)

Comment: @Samiron Your approach is actually better, especially when one or both of the files is long. Not only does mine store the entire essay in memory, it also scans from the beginning of the text for each word in the word list; yours, on the other hand, only stores unique words and uses fast hash lookups.

Comment: @Samiron Note that neither of our solutions works for words containing punctuation, e.g. the word `it's` in the essay will be matched by `it` in the word list. Funny characters in the word list words will also screw it up since we don't use `quotemeta` or `\Q...\E`, e.g. the word `a` in the essay will be matched by `[bar]` in the word list.

Comment: @Samiron Nevermind my first comment...I misread your code (it was about one in the morning my time) and thought you were putting the entire essay file into a hash, which would be more efficient for large files. Still a good solution, though, and I didn't know about `@-`, so thanks!

Comment: You are right in your `quotemeta` related comment. The regular expressions, contents of wordlist.txt etc might needs to be tuned based on their business logics. And as you mentioned, adding `quotemeta`or `\Q...\E` would make it more flexible. I think the best solution would be combinning the `hash lookup` along with `quotemeta` options.